# How to load a model without cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, command-line

I download the code of [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/) tutorial and run it. I've tried to change model. But I am unable to understand how to change this line:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
```

According to the [document](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#ga29d0ea5e52b1d1a6c2681e3f7d68473a). `readNetFromCaffe()` reads a network model stored in Caffe framework's format. But my model is EffcientDet it is not in Caffe framework's format. Also function returns net object. Is it possible to use my model without `readNetFromCaffe()`

I changed these lines

```
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
```

to

```
#ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
#   help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
net = (args["model"])
```

I get an error because I can't load my model. I just assign the name of the model I've given on the command line.